# Android Application, problems advertising service on network

Tags: java, android, networking

Currently working on an Android application that enables people to alert other people in the same network that have said app installed on their android device. It uses Java's Network Service Discovery classes to accomplish this.

There's a background android service that advertises a network service to the network, so the device can be seen and communicated with by other devices in the network. It calls

```
mNsdManager.registerService(serviceInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mRegistrationListener);
```

to register the service on the network.
This background service runs at all times when the device is connected to a WiFi-network to ensure availability.

All the functionalities that have been implemented work fine, until the phone gets put to sleep.
When that happens the network service, which is supposed to be broadcasted at all times, stops showing up.
I assume this is not a bug, but normal behaviour since the Android background service is stopped(?) and as such stops sending packets to the network when the phone is put to sleep.

How can I solve this issue? Do I need to take a different approach entirely?